# Django and Premade mysql databases

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have two database in mysql that have tables built from another program I have wrote to get data, etc. However I would like to use django and having trouble understanding the model/view after going through the tutorial and countless hours of googling. My problem is I just want to access the data and displaying the data. I tried to create routers and done inspectdb to create models. Only to get 1146 (table doesn't exist issues). I have a unique key.. Lets say (a, b) and have 6 other columns in the table. I just need to access those 6 columns row by row. I'm getting so many issues. If you need more details please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

inspectdb is far from being perfect. If you have an existing db with a bit of complexity you will end up probably changing a lot of code generated by this command. One you're done btw it should work fine. What's your exact issue? If you run inspectdb and it creates a model of your table you should be able to import it and use it like a normal model, can you share more details or errors you are getting while querying the table you're interested in?